# Put ggplot layer (error bars) under other ggplot layer (points)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Is there a way to put the error bars behind the points in the example below? So basically there will be no line going through the colored shape.

```
#generate fake dataset with three columns 'x', 'value', and 'variable'
data <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 3),
                   value=c(2,4,NA,6,2,3,5,4,3,6,9,7,4,3,5),
                   SE = c(0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2, 0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2),
                   variable=rep(paste0('series', 1:3), each=5))
data
#plot all three series on the same chart using geom_line()
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=value, group =variable)) + geom_line(colour = "black") + geom_point(aes(shape=variable, color=variable, fill = variable), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 22, 23))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('black','black', 'black'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9')) +
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1), legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1)  ) + geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE), colour="black", width=.2)
```

[image]

Comment: The order in which you add geoms is the order in which they are drawn. If you want the points on top, add `geom_points` last.

Comment: Not a perfect dupe, but between the comment above and that thread you should be able to solve your problem.